# How to prohibit user`s IP who login denied for three time in dropbear

Tags: linux

Excuse me, I would like to ask that I want to modify the dropbear to add one

function.  I already download the sourcecode of dropbear-0.52 and i have been

read for them  for a long time but i dont know which c.file I should modify..

I want to add function like this, if user login denied for three times,

prohibit their ip for 30 mins

and i have tried to modified the cli.auth, but it doesnt work

```
/*
if(ses.authstate.failcount >= 3){
        if (cli_ses.auth_interact_failed) {
            finished = 0;
        } else {
            cli_auth_interactive();
            cli_ses.lastauthtype = AUTH_TYPE_INTERACT;
            finished = 1;
    }
*/
```

I hope someone can help me to slove this problem, thanks a lot

Comment: Have you looked at fail2ban?

Comment: Sorry,Do you mean the file it called fail2ban?
I didnt see this file in source code.

Comment: fail2ban is a software that specializes in blocking after failed logins. It should work with dropbear, so you don't have to reinvent the wheel. Although a little patch to dropbear might still be required.

Answer (score 0):

**svr-auth.c** file in dropbear checking for password and retries look at **send_msg_userauth_failure**() function in that you have **ses.authstate.failcount**
variable which keeps track of successive login failure, if it reaches to 3 you can block connection from that ip in **svr-main.c** file for 30 mins

**svr-auth.c**

```
if (ses.authstate.failcount >= MAX_AUTH_TRIES) {
        char * userstr;
        /* XXX - send disconnect ? */
        TRACE(("Max auth tries reached, exiting"))

        if (ses.authstate.pw_name == NULL) {
            userstr = "is invalid";
        } else {
            userstr = ses.authstate.pw_name;
        }
        dropbear_exit("Max auth tries reached - user '%s' from %s",
                userstr, svr_ses.addrstring);
    }
```

svr-main.c

```
                /* child */
#ifdef DEBUG_FORKGPROF
                extern void _start(void), etext(void);
                monstartup((u_long)&_start, (u_long)&etext);
#endif /* DEBUG_FORKGPROF */

                getaddrstring(&remoteaddr, NULL, &remote_port, 0);
                dropbear_log(LOG_INFO, "Child connection from %s:%s", remote_host, remote_port);

///Ignore connection here  for 30 mins if you found 3 times login failure 

                m_free(remote_host);
                m_free(remote_port);

#ifndef DEBUG_NOFORK
                if (setsid() < 0) {
                    dropbear_exit("setsid: %s", strerror(errno));
                }
#endif

                /* make sure we close sockets */
                for (i = 0; i < listensockcount; i++) {
                    m_close(listensocks[i]);
                }

                m_close(childpipe[0]);

                /* start the session */
                svr_session(childsock, childpipe[1]);
                /* don't return */
                dropbear_assert(0);
            }
```

Comment: How are you ? Rahul R Dhobi.

thank for your imformation and code.

i had modified the two files svr-auth.c and svr-main.c

and compile then install in my Embedded system

but i tried to test it for serveral times, it looks ineffctive 

could you give me a hand again ? Thanks

Comment: I overwrite that code you provide,  when I test to login in ssh, it still doesn't  ban the user who login for three times .. I m really sorry to bother you